# Conditional Expectation Over Conditional Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If we have the conditional expectation:
$$\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{Var}(Y|X_1,X_2)|X_1=x_1]$$
how do we determine to which distribution the expectation is taken with respect?

I understand that $\mathrm{E}[Y|X]$ is taken with respect to $p(Y|X)$. And I also know that $\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{Var}(Y|X_1)|X_2]$ is taken with respect to $p(X_1 | X_2)$ since $\mathrm{Var}(Y|X_1)$ is a function of $X_1$. But in the question, since $X_1 = x_1$ is fixed, does it mean that $\mathrm{Var}(Y|X_1,X_2)$ given $X_1 = x_1$ is just a function of $X_2$ alone? Is it then correct to say that the conditional expectation in question is taken with respect to $p(X_2 | X_1)$?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

**Edit 1**

I guess I just found out the answer.
$\mathrm{Var}(Y|X_1,X_2)$ is a function of $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$, therefore, the expectation is taken with respect to $p(X_1,X_2|X_1)=p(X_2|X_1)p(X_1)/p(X_1)=p(X_2|X_1)$. That is, the expectation is taken with respect to $p(X_2 | X_1 = x_1)$.

Comment: If $\text{Var}(Y|X_1,X_2) = \mathbb{E}[Y^2|(X_1,X_2)]-\mathbb{E}^2[Y|(X_1,X_2)]$. Then $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(Y^2|X_1,X_2)]-\mathbb{E}^2[Y|(X_1,X_2)] | X_1 = x_1]$ is equal to: $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y^2|X_1,X_2] | X_1=x_1]-\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}^2[Y|(X_1,X_2)]| X_1 = x_1]$. If someone could confirm the steps and continue correctly with the conditioning for $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}^2[W|Z]|Z=z]$ I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Third step really helped me to come with the answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I couldn't think of a way to show what you wanted exactly,  so I tried to give you some tools. Cheers!